Designing a semi lights out puzzle game, how to know if it's solvable
I'm making a puzle for a game I'm programming with similar design as lights out.
Basically it's a spider web with different nodes which are connected by lines, whenever you press a node, it changes the line state from still to vibrating and the other way around. In the puzle there can be nodes with more or less connections and the initial state of the lines can be both still or vibrating. The objective is that all lines are vibrating.
How can I check if one of my designs can be solved or not? I've tried working with matrices and different rules but I'm finding it kind of hard and would love some advice.

Do you limit any node to be visited once?

Do you mean to say, " it changes the line state" actually "LINES"?

I believe it is not only easy to check, but also easy to solve.  At least if a line connects exactly 2 nodes.  (There is no additional node in the middle of a line, for instance)
The game is linear, it only depends on the parity of the number of times you click a node.  The game boils down to decide whether you click a node or not.
Since a line connects exactly two nodes, once you have decided to click or not one node, you immediately know whether you need to click the other node.
Let's say you color the nodes red respectively green depending on whether you click it respectively don't click it.
So start with one node, decide it is red.  Then consider its neighbors and the lines connecting to them.  Knowing the color of one end forces the color of the other end, so the color of the neighbors is uniquely determined.  Then consider the neighbor's neighbors, and continue like this coloring all remaining nodes.  If at any time you loop back on a node already colored, and it is the wrong color, then you know there is no solution.  If not, you end up with a solution.
If you find no solution, there is still a chance.  Redo the same process but coloring the initial cell green.  If again you found no solution the web is not solvable.  And if you have tried both colors for the initial node you will actually find all possible solutions.
PS: now that I think of it, if it is solvable one way, it is also solvable the other way.  The difference between the two solutions is just the inversion of all the colors.  It does not affect the resulting state of any line.  That means you only have to decide arbitrarily the color of any one node and the rest follows logically one line at a time.

By following your line of thought, it is actually not that hard to see that a position is solvable if and only if it has evenly many still segments on every cycle. This might be a sufficiently nice criterion to check directly. (I'm going to leave this here as a comment, since it builds more on your answer than it does on my own.)

I thought of this, actually.  But if that requires testing all possible loops, that can be huge in the general case.  And I am not sure what subset of the loops is sufficient to be tested.  Unless we are talking about a planar graph.

I assume that at least TWO lines are connected to a node (if this is a spider web:)). So when you press a node both lines change status?

The way I understand the game, clicking a node reverses the state of all the lines connected to that node.

It seems that this can be viewed in the same manner as the original game.
By enumerating the lines, we can view a state of the game as an element of the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, where $n$ is the number of lines and a coordinate being 0 (resp. 1) indicates that the line is vibrating (resp. still). Now, as in the original game, we can make the critical observation that pressing a node is exactly the same thing as adding the vector that has 1's exactly in the positions corresponding to the lines adjacent to the node. Call the vectors we obtain in this manner $v_1,...,v_r$, where $r$ is the number of nodes. From this description, it is then clear that a state $v$ can be solved if and only if we are able to express $v$ as a linear combination of the $v_i$.
Now, since your graph will typically have many more lines than nodes, the space spanned by the $v_i$ will generally be a proper subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ (In fact, unless I am mistaken, every state will be solvable if and only if your graph is a forest). As such, obtaining a helpful, practical description of the space of solvable states will most probably depend on the specifics of the graph.
